# iPhone ALAssets: Can assets be destructively edited?

Tags: ios, alassetslibrary

Looking at the [ALAssetsLibrary API](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/Reference/Reference.html), I see a few methods for creating new assets:
`writeImageDataToSavedPhotosAlbum:metadata:completionBlock:`
`writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:metadata:completionBlock:`
`writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:orientation:completionBlock:`
`writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:completionBlock:`

These seem to indicate that you should only be creating new assets. My question though is this: Is there a way to make destructive edits to assets? Or do you always create new images for the edits? I'm hoping for the latter as I want each asset to be treated as a unique, created only once asset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found no possible way to remove or alter assets in the library. Its kind of a pain when I create items in the assets library and I cannot remove them. But that appears to be apples wishes. Most likely because they do not want an app to be able to delete images and videos from the users library. Only by going to the camera app or another "Apple" app will the asset be able to be removed.

I kind of wish they would let you popup a delete confirmation window for an asset to let the user decide on a (apple created) confirmation page.

Comment: Thank you for your confirmation. I thought this was the case, but wanted to verify with another developer. For my needs, I need to know whether an asset was updated or not (after creation). This helps me avoid having to worry about that; If I have a reference to the asset URL and it's in the asset library, then I can assume it's the same version. Sorry for the inconvenience this causes you though.

Comment: If the asset was "Edited" it would be removed and re created. at which point the assets-library:// url would be invalid as it contains a GUID. and the chances of getting that guid again is impossibly slim. Even editing it in the photo app (such as cropping or rotating) will recreate the asset rather than edit it.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it, but as of iOS 5 it seems to be possible to edit an image using the `setImageData` method on `ALAsset`, if the image is flagged as editable (only if the image was originally created by your app):

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAsset_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/ALAsset/setImageData:metadata:completionBlock:

It doesn't seem to be possible to delete images though.